# How to create a CGImageRef from a NSBitmapImageRep?

Tags: objective-c, cgimageref, nsbitmapimagerep

How can I create a `CGImageRef` from a `NSBitmapImageRep`?
Or how can I define a complete new `CGImageRef` in the same way as the `NSBitmapImageRep`? The definition of a `NSBitmapImageRep` works fine. But I need an image as `CGImageRef`.

```
unsigned char *plane = (unsigned char *)[data bytes]; // data = 3 bytes for each RGB pixel

NSBitmapImageRep* imageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
                              initWithBitmapDataPlanes:     &plane
                              pixelsWide:                   width
                              pixelsHigh:                   height
                              bitsPerSample:                depth
                              samplesPerPixel:              channel
                              hasAlpha: NO
                              isPlanar: NO
                              colorSpaceName: NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace
                              //bitmapFormat: NSAlphaFirstBitmapFormat
                              bytesPerRow:                  channel * width
                              bitsPerPixel:                 channel * depth
                             ];
```

I have no idea how to create the `CGImageRef` from the `NSBitmapImageRep` or how to define a new `CGImageRef`:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, depth, channel*depth, channel*width, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), ... );
```

Please, can somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is by using the `CGImage` property (introduced in 10.5):

```
CGImageRef image = imageRep.CGImage;
```

---

Documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBitmapImageRep/CGImage

> **Return Value**
>
> Returns an autoreleased CGImageRef opaque type based on
>   the receiver’s current bitmap data.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> The returned CGImageRef has pixel dimensions that are
>   identical to the receiver’s. This method might return a preexisting
>   CGImageRef opaque type or create a new one. If the receiver is later
>   modified, subsequent invocations of this method might return different
>   CGImageRef opaque types.

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet, it seems you're starting with an `NSData` object. So, your question seems to be how to create a `CGImage` from a data object. In that case, there's no reason to go through `NSBitmapImageRep`.

You were almost there with the call to `CGImageCreate()`. You just needed to figure out how to supply a `CGDataProvider` to it. You can create a `CGDataProvider` from an `NSData` pretty directly, once you realize that `NSData` is toll-free bridged with `CFData`. So:

```
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);
CGImageRef image = CGImageCreate(width, height, depth / 3, depth, channel*width, colorspace, kCGImageAlphaNone, provider, NULL, TRUE, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
```